# How do you get List<Type> with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I have am getting a method, and checking `method.getParameterTypes()[0]`, which is a `java.util.List`.  But I want to figure out what the containing type is, for instance if it's a `java.util.List<String>` I want to figure out that it should hold strings.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Type listType = method.getGenericParameterTypes()[0];
if (listType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
    Type elementType = ((ParameterizedType) listType).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Note that the element type needn't be an actual `Class` like `String` -- it could be a type variable, a wildcarded type, etc.

You can read more about scraping generics info from reflected items [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/generics.html) and [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained).

Comment: +1 If your method argument is List<?> you will get back ?, even if you passed in a List<String> to the method from the calling code.

Comment: Where are you getting method from?

Comment: You can use this approach only for getting formal parameters were used in method declaration (args or result). Real parameters of generic type that was used in call can't be analysed by reflection.

Comment: If you want to identify any Collection type and not just List, you can write : 
if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(listType)) {}

Answer (score 3):

It's simple : you can't. At compile time, Java erases generic types (see [Type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923624/java-type-erasure-vs-fieldgetgenerictype-and-methodgetgenericreturntype) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3403976/1679537) for more information about `GetGenericType` (which I didn't know about, honestly), but it seems rather limited.

Comment: I was going to write the same. +1

Comment: I was afraid you would say that.  I wonder how jackson takes care of this when deserializing lists from json...

Comment: Looks like Jackson uses "[super type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html)", which are actually anonymous classes which extend `TypeReference` and hardcode the generic types into their class object.

Comment: It is true that an runtime, you can't reflect on some object for its `Class` and know that it was instantiated as a `List<String>`, `Iterable<Integer>`, etc.

However, if you have a `Method`, `Class`, `Field`, etc., you can discern any generics involved in the method's arguments or return type, field's type, class's superclass/implemented interfaces, etc.

Comment: The question explicitly states that he has a Method object, so it **is** possible. Thus, this answer is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I did as below

in here : your class is initialize as clazz (eg - Company.Class) and your Collection as

> `List<Employees> companyEmployee`
>
> `String collectionType`- List
>
> `String collectionContent`  - Employee

---

```
Method[] methodList = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
Method classMethod = methodList[0];

String[] collection= classMethod.getReturnType().toString().split("\\.");

String collectionType = collection[collection.length - 1]

String collectionContent = classMethod.getGenericReturnType().getTypeName().split("<")[1].split(">")[0]
```