# Is it possible to access Java 8 type information at runtime?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, type-annotation

Assuming I have the following member in a class which makes use of Java 8 type annotations:

```
private List<@Email String> emailAddresses;
```

Is it possible to read the `@Email` annotation given on the String type use at runtime using reflection? If so, how would this be done?

Update: That's the definition of the annotation type:

```
@Target(value=ElementType.TYPE_USE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Email {}
```

Comment: Have you tried and defined such an annotation and used it? I haven't, but I doubt this applies to generics since they are erased at runtime... Logically, so would be your annotation

Comment: I have declared the annotation and used it (updated the question to include the annotation definition). I can access the element type of the list, `String` (which is actually not erased). What I don't know is how to access the annotation.

Comment: @Gunnar Considering Type Erasure, why wasn't String list type erased?

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha type erasure doesn't apply to the declared types used in field or method definitions. E.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923624/java-type-erasure-vs-fieldgetgenerictype-and-methodgetgenericreturntype) for more information.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The reflection type representing this kind of structure is called [`AnnotatedParameterizedType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedParameterizedType.html). Here is an example of how to get your annotation:

```
// get the email field 
Field emailAddressField = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("emailAddresses");

// the field's type is both parameterized and annotated,
// cast it to the right type representation
AnnotatedParameterizedType annotatedParameterizedType =
        (AnnotatedParameterizedType) emailAddressField.getAnnotatedType();

// get all type parameters
AnnotatedType[] annotatedActualTypeArguments = 
        annotatedParameterizedType.getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments();

// the String parameter which contains the annotation
AnnotatedType stringParameterType = annotatedActualTypeArguments[0];

// The actual annotation
Annotation emailAnnotation = stringParameterType.getAnnotations()[0]; 

System.out.println(emailAnnotation);  // @Email()
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the down-cast to `AnnotatedParameterizedType` and thus didn't see `getAnnotatedActualTypeArguments()`.