# Getting Java 8 ElementType.TYPE_USE annotations at runtime

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, java-8

If I have an annotation with an @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE), the compiler lets me get away with adding an annotation to a line of code in a method:

```
@Description("hello")
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

How can I retrieve any information about this annotation at runtime?

This question is not the same as [Is it possible to access Java 8 type information at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374612/is-it-possible-to-access-java-8-type-informations-at-runtime), because in that case the annotation was on a field declaration.

Comment: You have never been able to inspect code in a method body through reflection. Anything annotated in a method body is only useful in static code analysis.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: it might be worth adding that this static code analysis can be done at runtime as the information is contained in the class file but that requires a byte code processing library beyond the scope of Java’s built-in Reflection.